# Was bedeutet aufsinken in dem Satz unten?

Tags: standard-german, separable-verb

Was bedeutetet aufsinken?
Beispiel: Ein Tauchboot **sank** um 156m **auf** nun 233m unter dem Meeresspiegel.

Answer (score 11):

In dem Beispielsatz bezeichnet "auf" das Ergebnis des Sinkvorgangs:

Das Tauchboot sank

- von 77 m
- um 156 m
- auf 233 m

unter dem Meeresspiegel.

[image: Illustration der Unterschiede zwischen von, um und auf eine Tiefe sinken]

Comment: Schönes Bildchen! (+1)

Answer (score 9):

Das Verb lautet nur "sinken" (das Wort "aufsinken" gibt es nicht). Es hat hier nur zwei Präpositionen gleichzeitig:

> Das Boot sinkt *um* 100 Meter = Es ist jetzt 100 Meter tiefer als vorher.

> Das Boot sinkt *auf* 100 Meter = Es ist jetzt 100 Meter unter der Oberfläche.

Beide Angaben können auch gleichzeitig gemacht werden, und das tut der Beispielsatz.

Comment: 'das Wort "aufsinken" gibt es nicht' - diese Aussage halte ich für etwas gewagt, denn gerade "Richtungspräfixe" lassen sich im Deutschen recht flexibel mit Bewegungsverben kombinieren. Es mag nicht häufig vorkommen, aber ich würde in einem entsprechenden Kontext "aufsinken" ohne zu stolpern verstehen als "eine sinkende Bewegung, die damit endet, dass das Sinkende Ding irgendwo aufliegt". (Deine Erklärung ist im Kontext des OPs natürlich korrekt.)

Comment: Im ersten Moment würde ich "aufsinken" als Gegenteil von "absinken" verstehen, was wiederum etwas anderes wäre als @O.R.Mapper versteht und an sich keinen Sinn macht. Ich würde "Sinken" und "Absinken" fast Synonym gebrauchen, allerdings gibt es wohl die Auffassung, dass "Absinken" heißt das es ein definiertes Ende gibt. In dem Fall wäre es wieder nahezu identisch mit dem Verständnis von Mapper. Kurzum: Ich meiner Meinung nach (Muttersprachler, kein Sprachwissenschaftler) ist 'Aufsinken' nicht eindeutig.

Answer (score 1):

Die deutsche Sprache hat zahlreiche trennbare Verben. Diese entstehen aus einem Verb durch Hinzufügung eines Präfixes (wobei sich eine völlig neue Bedeutung ergeben kann).

Ein Beispiel ist *aussteigen*, das aus dem Verb *steigen* durch Voranstellung von *aus* entsteht. In einem Satz wie "Er steigt aus dem Auto aus" wird das Verb wieder in seine Bestandteile zerlegt.

Allerdings kommen nicht alle denkbaren Kombinationen aus Verben und Präfixen offiziell als trennbare Verben vor. Im Zweifelsfall hilft nur ein Blick in ein Wörterbuch wie den Duden. In einem Satz wie

> Ein Tauchboot **sank** um 156m auf nun 233m unter dem Meeresspiegel.

ist durchaus nicht von vorneherein klar, ob nur das Verb *sinken*  verwendet wird oder ob *umsinken* bzw. *aufsinken* gemeint ist.

Das Verb *[umsinken](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/umsinken)* gibt es tatsächlich ("er wurde ohnmächtig und sank um"), passt aber nicht in den Kontext. Dagegen existiert *aufsinken* nicht.

Eine tiefere sprachliche Logik in Hinblick auf "zulässige Kombinationen" sollte man nicht erwarten. Die Verben *steigen* und *sinken* beschreiben Bewegungen nach oben und unten. Aus *steigen* können dann korrekt *aufsteigen* und *absteigen* gebildet werden, aus *sinken* aber nur *absinken*.

Für Personen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen, ergibt sich eine weitere Schwierigkeit bei Wortkombinationen wie *steigt auf*. Es kann sich um die konjugierte Form von *auf (etwas) steigen* (Verb + Präposition) oder von *aufsteigen* (trennbares Verb) handeln. Nur aus dem Kontext ergibt sich die richtige Interpretation. Beispiele: *Er steigt auf die Leiter* und *Die Mannschaft steigt auf (in eine höhere Liga)*.